# Building a WP7 app with tiles using standard controls

Tags: windows-phone-7

I would like to build an app with an interface with touch-enabled tiles similar to WP7 home screen tiles with a background color and different textblocks. Do you know how can I do it using standard controls? Are there already made user controls that can be used for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Creating something like the home/start screen could be confusing to users. (You wouldn't create a PC app which looks like a desktop.) Creating something like the hub experiences may be more appropriate.

Have a look at the [HubTile](http://www.windowsphonegeek.com/articles/Windows-Phone-HubTile-in-depth-Part1-key-concepts-and-API) in the [toolkit](http://silverlight.codeplex.com/releases/view/71550). It was created for just this scenario.